# How to install python ftplib in windows?

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I want to write some ftp program using python. Please help me to install "ftplib" in windows 7.

I have tried to install it but not succeed.

Comment: If your problem is solved, please select the answer below

Answer (score 14):

[`ftplib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#module-ftplib) is a built-in Python module, you do not need to install it. Check its documentation [`here`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#module-ftplib)

From Python console:

```
>>> import ftplib
>>>
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'ftplib']
```